# How to update from within a model method

Tags: python, django

I have the following method I am trying to write:

```
class MTurk(models.Model):
    ...

    def parse(self, url):

        res = requests.get(url)
        node = html.fromstring(res.content)
        data = MTurk()._parse_page(node)

        self.update(**data)
```

However, when I try and do `self.update(**data)` it tells me:

> AttributeError: 'MTurk' object has no attribute 'update'

Normally I would do `MTurk.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).update(**data)`, but is there a way to do this from within the model method itself without having to re-call everything?

Comment: I'm not sure you're supposed to be able to update the model within the model itself. It's not a very django-ish way if doing it, normally you'd like to save the model outside the model (basically from the method that is calling `parse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update` function doesn't seem to be accessible from an individual object, but is rather used on a [QuerySet](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L718).

It's however not a very Djangonic way of handling that kind of functionality, but you'd rather want to save the model outside the model, basically from the function/place that called `parse` in the first place, basically like this:

```
# Fetch an object
mturk = MTurk.objects.get(id=1)
# Call the parse method
mturk.parse(my_url)
# Save the object
mturk.save()
```

You could however still call the `save` function from within the model of course, in that case you'd just replace the `update` function with a `save` function, and you'd need to store the values to the model with `self`.

The `save` function also takes an argument `update_fields=[]` in which you can specify which fields you want to save (and ignore the rest). This might be what you're looking for.

```
class MTurk(models.Model):
    ...

    def parse(self, url):

        res = requests.get(url)
        node = html.fromstring(res.content)
        data = MTurk()._parse_page(node)

        self.data_1 = node # Store some data
        self.data_2 = data # Store some more data
        # Only save the given fields
        self.save(update_fields=["data_1", "data_2])
```

Comment: Is it slower than calling update from the views.py?